# Using javascript: How can a variable be added to a string containing quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, variables, url

The following is an extract from a javascript file.

**Correct string:**

```
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/folder/filename.aspx")%>'
```

**How can a variable be inserted within the URL?** *(As below)*

```
var variable = "filename.aspx"
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/folder/" + variable + ")%>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't**.
`ResolveUrl` is something that is translated to a string on the server side while your variable is a js var.
What you can do is maybe:

```
var variable = "filename.aspx"
url = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/folder/___MYVAR___")%>' // this will create a /folder/___MYVAR__
url = url.replace('___MYVAR___', variable); // this will create /folder/filename.aspx
```